# How to break long citations on a multirow tabular environment?

Tags: citing, line-breaking, tabularx, multirow

so I have the following table which I intend to show a summary of some research papers:

```
\documentclass[qualidr]{ppgco}
%Não altere o comando seguinte. O título de seu trabalho será especificado mais adiante.
\title{Template de Monografia do PPGCO}

\usepackage{cmap}               % Mapear caracteres especiais no PDF
\usepackage{lmodern}                % Usa a fonte Latin Modern          
\usepackage{makeidx}                % Cria o indice
\usepackage{hyperref}           % Controla a formação do índice
\usepackage{lastpage}           % Usado pela Ficha catalográfica
\usepackage{indentfirst}            % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
\usepackage{nomencl}            % Lista de simbolos
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
% ---
%Centralizar verticalmenre em tabularx
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
% ---
% Pacotes adicionais, usados apenas no âmbito do Modelo eesc
% ---
\usepackage{lipsum}                    % para geração de dummy text
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!htb]
\caption{My broken table.}
\label{tab:help}
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|X|l|X|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Method}  & \textbf{Dataset}  & \textbf{Some text}  & \textbf{Result}      \\ \hline
\cite{papastergiou2018tensor}     & This works fine     & A really long text, which works well    & 84,67\% (Ac)   \\ \hline
\cite{jorgensen2018exploiting}    & No problem here & Probably because there aren't multirows    & 0,950 (AUC)   \\ \hline
\cite{jiang2018effective}       & Perfect        & Another one that is clear      & 97,96\%  (Ac)           \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\footnotesize{\cite{watanabe2016semi}}}    & Now here,  & \multirow{2}{*}{I wonder why}  & 93,70\% (Ac)  \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
      & we have problems   &                       & 88,40\%  (Ac)     \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\cite{di2016feature}}     &It's because  & \multirow{2}{*}{But how to solve it?}       & 100,00\%  (Ac)  \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
  & of the multirow   &        & 100,00\% (Ac)     \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}



\bibliography{bib/abntex2-modelo-references}


\end{document}
```

which outputs

[image]

The long citations break well on regular rows, but not on the multirows. Any tips to solve it are greatly appreciated.

I am using multirow and tabularx packages.

Thanks

EDIT: The refs being used

```
@article{papastergiou2018tensor,
  title={Tensor Decomposition for Multiple-Instance Classification of High-Order Medical Data},
  author={Papastergiou, Thomas and Zacharaki, Evangelia I and Megalooikonomou, Vasileios},
  journal={Complexity},
  volume={2018},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Hindawi}
}

@incollection{jorgensen2018exploiting,
  title={Exploiting multiple color representations to improve colon cancer detection in whole slide H\&E stains},
  author={J{\o}rgensen, Alex Skovsbo and Emborg, Jonas and R{\o}ge, Rasmus and {\O}stergaard, Lasse Riis},
  booktitle={Computational Pathology and Ophthalmic Medical Image Analysis},
  pages={61--68},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@inproceedings{jiang2018effective,
  title={An Effective Multi-classification Method for NHL Pathological Images},
  author={Jiang, Huiyan and Li, Zhongkuan and Li, Siqi and Zhou, Fucai},
  booktitle={2018 IEEE International Conference on Systems, Man, and Cybernetics (SMC)},
  pages={763--768},
  year={2018},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{watanabe2016semi,
  title={Semi-Supervised Feature Transformation for Tissue Image Classification},
  author={Watanabe, Kenji and Kobayashi, Takumi and Wada, Toshikazu},
  journal={PloS one},
  volume={11},
  number={12},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Public Library of Science}
}

@incollection{di2016feature,
  title={A feature learning framework for histology images classification},
  author={Di Ruberto, Cecilia and Putzu, Lorenzo and Arabnia, HR and Quoc-Nam, T},
  booktitle={Emerging trends in applications and infrastructures for computational biology, bioinformatics, and systems biology: systems and applications},
  pages={37--48},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Elsevier Press}
}
```

Comment: Hi Guilherme, welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please provide a complete MWE, so others can directly start to debug and do not have to find out which class you use, etc.?

Comment: Why do you encase `\cite{watanabe2016semi}` in a `\multirow` directive? It's entirely unnecessary.

Comment: You can use  `\multirow{2}{=}{…}` to specify the multirow cell has the fixed width of the current column.

Comment: @Bernard I can't believe it's that easy! Thank you. Solved! And also thanks TobiBS and Mico for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

You may liked (mostly off-topic suggestions):

**Edit:** added bibliography

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @article{papastergiou2018tensor,
  title={Tensor Decomposition for Multiple-Instance Classification of High-Order Medical Data},
  author={Papastergiou, Thomas and Zacharaki, Evangelia I and Megalooikonomou, Vasileios},
  journal={Complexity},
  volume={2018},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Hindawi}
}

@incollection{jorgensen2018exploiting,
  title={Exploiting multiple color representations to improve colon cancer detection in whole slide H\&E stains},
  author={J{\o}rgensen, Alex Skovsbo and Emborg, Jonas and R{\o}ge, Rasmus and {\O}stergaard, Lasse Riis},
  booktitle={Computational Pathology and Ophthalmic Medical Image Analysis},
  pages={61--68},
  year={2018},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@inproceedings{jiang2018effective,
  title={An Effective Multi-classification Method for NHL Pathological Images},
  author={Jiang, Huiyan and Li, Zhongkuan and Li, Siqi and Zhou, Fucai},
  booktitle={2018 IEEE International Conference on Systems, Man, and Cybernetics (SMC)},
  pages={763--768},
  year={2018},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{watanabe2016semi,
  title={Semi-Supervised Feature Transformation for Tissue Image Classification},
  author={Watanabe, Kenji and Kobayashi, Takumi and Wada, Toshikazu},
  journal={PloS one},
  volume={11},
  number={12},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Public Library of Science}
}

@incollection{di2016feature,
  title={A feature learning framework for histology images classification},
  author={Di Ruberto, Cecilia and Putzu, Lorenzo and Arabnia, HR and Quoc-Nam, T},
  booktitle={Emerging trends in applications and infrastructures for computational biology, bioinformatics, and systems biology: systems and applications},
  pages={37--48},
  year={2016},
  publisher={Elsevier Press}
}
\end{filecontents}
%%%%
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
%%%%

\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!htb]
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells
\caption{My broken table.}
\label{tab:help}
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{|L|l|L|S[table-format=3.2]<{\%}l|}
    \hline
\thead{Method}  & \thead{Dataset}  & \thead{Some text}  & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\thead{Result}}    \\
    \hline
\citet*{papastergiou2018tensor}     
    & This works fine     
        & A really long text, which works well    
            &  84,67    &   (Ac)   \\ \hline
\citet*{jorgensen2018exploiting}    
    & No problem here
        & Probably because there aren't multirows    
            &   0,95    &   (AUC)   \\ \hline
\citet*{jiang2018effective}       
    & Perfect        
        & Another one that is clear      
            &  97,96    &   (Ac)    \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{=}{\citet*{watanabe2016semi}}  
    & Now here, 
        & \multirow{2.4}{=}{I wonder why} 
            &  93,70    &   (Ac)    \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-5}
    & we have problems   
        &   &  88,40    &   (Ac)    \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{=}{\citet*{di2016feature}}     
    & It's because  
        & \multirow{2.4}{=}{But how to solve it? By use of \texttt{=} instead of \texttt{* multirow} option}
            & 100,00    &   (Ac)    \\ \cline{2-2} \cline{4-5}
    & of the multirow   
        &   & 100,00    &   (Ac)    \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]